# How to configure and use MySQL with Django?

Tags: python, mysql, django, ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 system and have created a virtual environment also. I want to set up Django with MySQL database (PHPMyAdmin preferably) to work on my project. Please guide me with the required commands and set up lines.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about something that is fully documented and the OP obviously didn't even bother to read the doc.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/databases/#mysql-notes

Comment: Oh and yes: phpmyadmin is just a web-based admin interface.

Comment: I got my answer. thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily install xampp first from https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html

(Follow [these](https://www.unixmen.com/install-xampp-stack-ubuntu-14-04/) steps for xampp installation.)

Then follow the instructions as:

1. Install and run xampp from http://www.unixmen.com/install-xampp-stack-ubuntu-14-04/, then start Apache Web Server and MySQL Database from the GUI.
2. You can configure your web server as you want but by default web server is at `http://localhost:80` and database at `port 3306`, and PhpMyadmin at `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/`
3. From here you can see your databases and access them using very friendly GUI.
4. Create any database(`DB_NAME`) which you want to use on your Django Project.
5. Edit your settings.py file

   `DATABASES = {
   'default': {
       'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
       'NAME': 'DB_NAME',
       'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
       'PORT': '3306',
       'USER': 'root',
       'PASSWD': '',
   }}`
6. Install the following packages in the virtualenv (if you're using django on virtualenv, which is more preferred):

   `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev`

   `pip install MySQL-python`
7. That's it!! you have configured Django with MySQL in a very easy way.
8. Now run your Django project:

   `python manage.py migrate`

   `python manage.py runserver`